# Using javascript Jquery AJAX to preform a curl and pass -d -u

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, curl

OK, so I have a basic HTML page with jquery. I also have a CRM called Streak. I'm trying to integrate the two with a basic form.

Below is the streak docs. All references are using cURL. 
https://www.streak.com/api/#box

The command I'm trying to use below:

```
url -X PUT -d "name=NewBox" https://www.streak.com/api/v1/pipelines/{pipelinesKey}/boxes -u YOUR_API_KEY:
```

I want to use jQuery Ajax to send the request:

```
$.ajax("https://www.streak.com/api/v1/pipelines/LionTrade/boxes",
```

The thing that I don't understand is how do I send the other items in the cURL command, like the below?

```
-X PUT -d "name=NewBox" -u YOUR_API_KEY:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://www.streak.com/api/v1/pipelines/LionTrade/boxes",
  method: "PUT",
  data: "name=NewBox",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("YOUR_API_KEY:")
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

The default `contentType` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. You can set the `Authorization` header in `headers` for basic authentication

Comment: Thanks Bertrand, I'm having some issue with my connection to the API now. I'll test tomorrow and let you know

Comment: Sorry for the late response. This worked and fixed the issues. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad to help, you can accept the answer if your problem is solved